# postgresql how do I extract everything before the first 2 dots in an IP address?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a set of IP addresses in a column (such as 192.0.0.1) where I'd like to extract everything before the 2nd dot (192.0). As the amount of characters in a full IP address can differ I can't do a simple left() or right(), but need a substring() I suppose which I don't manage to figure out.

Any help would by highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t=# select substring('192.168.1.1' from '^\d*\.\d*');
 substring
-----------
 192.168
(1 row)
```

but also [look into](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-net.html) `cidr` and `inet` datatypes - It feels you invent a wheel maybe?..

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast help, works perfect for my use!

Comment: no worries. please accept the answer and read link - it may help you

Comment: Accepted, just upvoted first time, new here sorry :) Definitely will check the link out.